# How to display a binary state (ON/OFF) in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have built a GUI with matplotlib and it contains several plots of values versus time. Now I need a special plot which just shows if a value is on or off (binary state).

Kinda like a control lamp on an analog control panel. I have 5 of those on/off values and I dont know how to do it the best way.

The "lamps" must be updateable because I stream the data from serial and analyze it in real time in my GUI.

I attached a picture where you see my current GUI. In the bottom right corner is now a bar chart, I tried to visualize the ON/OFF state with a bar, but it didn't work well and I wasn't able to animate it.

[image]

So yeah, how could I display 5 values with each an ON/OFF state in that area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing via bar charts I would directly plot a number of rectangles and then dynamically change their color.

You can find the documentation for rectangular patches here: http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle

If you need some pointers on how to animate such a patch have a look here:
https://nickcharlton.net/posts/drawing-animating-shapes-matplotlib.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea! I am right now also looking into making a Qt GUI and using the elements like radi obuttons from the Qt Widgets. I would then implement the Matplotlib Graphs in a Qt Graph Widget.